Can you fetch VectorSource data before setting it on the VectorLayer in OpenLayers?
Working in OpenLayers 9, I'd like to avoid a blank map while I change the CQL_Filter of a VectorSource and refetch data to populate an existing vector layer. Currently, my code works like this:
//Get vector layer to update from map
const layerName = 'myLayer'
const vLyr = mapObj.getAllLayers().filter((lyr) => lyr.get('name') == layerName)[0] as VectorLayer<VectorSource<Feature<Geometry>>>;

//Make a new WFS request URL
const filter = 'dataset_year=' + hydroPlantFilters[layerName].filter.value; //dynamic filter value
const requestUrl = getWfsUrl(layerName, filter); //returns string URL

//Create new VectorSource
const newSrc = createVectorSource(requestUrl);

//Reset the VectorLayer Source with the new source; layer disappears from map here
vLyr.setSource(newSrc);

//Wait for new features to load, eventually they do and the layer appears on the map again
newSrc.on('featuresloadend', (event) => {
    if (!!event.features && event.features.length > 0) {
    console.log(vLyr.getSource()?.getFeatures());
    } else {
    console.log('no features found');
    }
});

The createVectorSource function looks like this:
export const createVectorSource = (requestUrl: string) => {
  const vSrc = new VectorSource({
    format: new GeoJSON({
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    }),
    loader: function (extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
      const url = requestUrl;
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      const onError = function () {
        console.log('error on wfs request');
      };
      xhr.onerror = onError;
      xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          const features: Feature<Geometry>[] = vSrc.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText) as Feature<Geometry>[];
          vSrc.addFeatures(features);
          success(features);
        } else {
          onError();
        }
      };
      xhr.send();
    },
  });

  return vSrc;
};


I've attempted to put the vLyr.setSource(newSrc) line inside the featuresloadend event listener function, but that function will never be hit if I don't alter the vLyr by using getSource().clear() or setSource() first.
Is there a way to trigger the load event directly on the VectorSource itself or does it have to be wrapped by a layer before it will fetch features?

Not sure it really solves your problem, but you don't have to create a new source when the filter changes. You can just change the URL that the loader function uses and run refresh() on the source.
That would clear all old features and fetch the new ones using the new filter and hopefully OpenLayers will wait to clear until the new ones are fetched. This is how we do it and I have never observed that the map goes blank, but on the other hand, we have very small amount of data to fetch.

Doesn't setUrl() only work on the url property of the source and not for switching out the loader function url? Or are you using setLoader() to update the whole loader function? Any chance you could add a code example of what you're describing?

You don't have to change the loader function. If you have defined your variable requestUrl in the outer scope, accessible to the loader function, you just change its value to contain a new filter. Next time loader is called (e.g after a refresh), the new value will be used. Here: https://github.com/origo-map/origo/blob/master/src/layer/wfssource.js is an example. It is a bit more complex as it is written as a class and supports BBOX. It doesn't have to be a class, but the idea is the same. Look at the setFilter()function. It only changes a variable accessible to the loader in outer scope.
